# csv file lost format and ask for updating

Tags: excel, csv, format, updating, opencsv

I got an issue with my current csv file. Please help to get my normal format back.
The data was normally displayed in separate column, for example:

```
name            address            link         user
AAA            126/5ggg         htpps://...     aa
BBB            263 GJ...        htpps://....    bb
```

Open it in Notepad, it shows the right position of data, please find the attachment:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUns2.png)

After 2 hours reopening it, the format disappeared and ask for update. Please find the photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YplcF.png)

It now shows everything in one or two columns. Please find the photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOfBg.png)

How can I get it back to be displayed in separate columns again?

Comment: could you open the file in a texteditor and show how it looks there?

Comment: @Bartors: I opened it in Notepad, and it shows the right format as the former format. How can i fix it in my csv file now, please?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the images, this is not a CSV (comma separated value) file -- note there are no ","'s between the fields, but rather looks like a TSV (or Tab separated values file).

I'm thinking the "update external source" may not be related - but not 100% on that.

All of the fields appear to be in column A, so first, widen the column to see the entire record(s). Second, try converting the first 5-10 records with `text to column` under the `Data` tab. Select values separated by tab (only the one check box).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jbowman. It cetrainy is not a CSV file as you'll run into troubel til the `hadress` (city and state are comma separated yet column names only mention `hadress`).

You should try to import your file as a TSV-file, here is a quick guide on how to do it:
[link](http://www.arj.no/2013/06/28/how-to-import-tsv-file-in-ms-excel/) 
And I do know which version of excel you are using but on mine you have to use "open" in stead of "import". And do remember to have "All files" when you are in the windows explorer.

Hope it helps.